# Vehicle dimension Database

Tags: database, size, dimensions

I am building an app for wrapping vehicles with graphics. I need a database of all the vehicles which has the dimensions of the vehicle. So for example it would have size of the hood, windshield, roof, side door and so on. Has anyone looked for this so far. Where would i find this, preferably free and I can pay for this also.

Comment: I don't know that there would already be something like this. I would search your competition and see if they have something similar... If they do you could probably find the data with very little research.

Answer (score 1):

http://mr-clipart.com/int/searchvehi.php?hest=CHEVR&threed=&anzahl=&mod=45 that should help you... If you want a database you could spend some time and put it together...